# Class 'clsGetHeaderValue' cannot be indexed because it has no default property

Tags: vb.net, .net-2.0

I am getting a strange error when I try to build my solution. The error occurs when I am calling the **oGetHeaderValue** function and passing the parameters.

```
Dim oGetHeaderValue As New clsGetHeaderValue

Dim returnString As String
returnString = oGetHeaderValue(strInvoiceNumber, strOrderNumber)
```

The error message is: Class 'clsGetHeaderValue' cannot be indexed because it has no default property.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're calling your instance `oGetHeaderValue` as if it's a method. It looks like you probably meant to call a function on it instead but missed out that bit.
So maybe your code should be:

```
Dim returnString As String = oGetHeaderValue.YourMethod(strInvoiceNumber, strOrderNumber)
```

Where `YourMethod` is whatever method you wanted to call.

And just to clarify after reading your question again, `oGetHeaderValue` is not a function, it's an instance of a class that might contain functions and subs etc.

Answer (score 2):

The confusion is caused by the fact that VB.Net uses `()` for array indexing as well as method calls.